# Intuition for Incrementing a Proportion

Tags: summation, fractions, percentages

I'm trying to understand a simple math concept intuitively. When you increase a sum by some percentage, why is it that the numbers that compose that sum are all increased at that percentage, instead of increasing at a percentage in proportion to the sum itself?

Put another way, why is it that if we have $ 2 \cdot 5 = 10 $. And we decide to increase $10$ by $50\%$ and obtain $15$, the sequence of numbers that compose $10$ increase by $50\%$ as well. So $2$ then increases to $3$, which gives $15$ as the sum. Why is this the case, rather than dividing the $50\%$ by $5$ giving $10\%$, and incrementing the each number in the sequence by $10\%$ instead?

Of course, the latter is clearly incorrect, but I'm curious if anyone has several intuitive ways to more clearly understand this basic idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very confused by your question, but you seem to be having trouble understanding a couple of things.

$\qquad (1)$: When a quantity is increased by $50\%$, we end up with $150\%$ of the original quantity.
More generally, when a quantity is increased by $x\%$, we end up with $(100+x)\%$ of the original quantity.
The end result is that the initial quantity is **multiplied** by $\frac{100+x}{100}$.
Similarly, if we were *decreasing* something by $x\%$, the end result is that the initial quantity is **multiplied** by $\frac{100-x}{100}$.

$\qquad (2)$: Multiplication is **commutative** and **associative**, meaning we can carry it out in steps, at each step calculating the product of any two factors in the multiplication.

In your example, we have that $10$ is multiplied by $\frac{100+50}{100}=\frac{150}{100}=1.5$.
Thus we have

$$15=1.5\times 10=1.5\times (2 \times 5)=(1.5\times 2)\times 5=3\times 5$$

We simply chose to carry out the multiplication $1.5\times 2$ before anything else, but we could very well have opted for $1.5\times 5$ and got that $15=2\times 7.5$, which is also true.

$\qquad(3)$: Multiplication **distributes over addition**, but not over multiplication.
In other words, the rule $a\times(b+c)=(a\times b)+(a\times c)$ is true, but the rule $a\times(b\times c)=(a\times b) \times (a\times c)$ is **false**.
This means that, for instance, we can write

$$10=2+2+2+2+2\\
10=5+5$$

so that

\begin{align}
15=1.5\times 10&=1.5\times(2+2+2+2+2)\\
&=(1.5\times 2)+(1.5\times 2)+(1.5\times 2)+(1.5\times 2)+(1.5\times 2)\\
&=3+3+3+3+3
\end{align}

and similarly

\begin{align}
15=1.5\times 10&=1.5\times(5+5)\\
&=(1.5\times 5)+(1.5\times 5)\\
&=7.5+7.5
\end{align}

but

\begin{align}
15=1.5\times 10&=1.5\times(2\times 5)\\
&\neq(1.5\times 2)\times(1.5\times 5)\\
&=3\times7.5=22.5
\end{align}